# What should application layer return? entity or dto?

Tags: oop, inversion-of-control, clean-architecture

In clean architecture, I implement restful api as an infrastructure,

the question is: what should the application layer return

1 - entity: this is what chatgpt answer, it say the application layer will return entity, then we will map it into dto in infrastructure layer (controller), but I think public the entity to the controller is not a good practice.

2 - dto: I think we should map the entity to dto in application layer, but incase the function need to serve more than one infrastructure, how should we implement it, for example a create post api which is need to use server sent event to send notif to client

what do you think, what should be the good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr: what chatGPT said... (kinda)

IMO, the important thing with the approach of Clean Architecture is the separation of concerns between layers, and the rule of dependancy which means that the inner layers (high level) know nothing about the outer layers (low level). This is because you don't want to have cascading and unexpected changes around the application.

[image]

According to the diagram, you can see that the application (Interactor) is returning a Response Model, and the controller is receiving the Response Model.

I think that the important thing is that the transport (controller) will format the Response Model into a response, and will encode it using the specific mechanism.

> I am not talking about an entity that has methods for Save/Update and such. For me, this is a job for the repository layer, and the entity is a mere DTO with maybe some business policy rules.

In pure Clean Architecture, you are right, the Response Model shouldn't contain an entity, but IMO, it doesn't matter what you are returning in the response, if the transport simply returns the response model data in the HTTP response body, you are coupling the entity to the transport. When the entity will change, the response will change (unknowingly), and worse, if you will want to change the response to the client, you will change the entity, which absolutely breaks the abstraction. This means that the entity and the application are aware of the http transport layer. (Even though these components don't have the word "HTTP" in them).

Need to note that this drawing is only a high-level idea about Clean Architecture. For example, I am working with Go (and go-kit like framework) which makes this separation super convenient. The application (domain service) returns an entity, but I have another component which is called "endpoint" that takes the entity and wraps it inside a Response Model (either the entity itself or related data). The transport takes the Response Model and formats it into the HTTP body. If I want to add another transport (for example gRPC), I need only to add another transport that uses the same endpoint, receives the same Response Model, and formats it to the appropriate mechanism.

If you won't make this separation, these two responses will be coupled.

Answer (score 1):

The application layer should return a DTO or as uncle bob calls them response models. The response models and the request models are part of the use case's api.

There are use cases that return response models that are very similar to the entity structure, e.g. when you have a use case get user profile data. Other use cases might only return a reference to an entity, e.g. if you have a place order use case the result might only be the order number.

Even though some response models are very similar to the entities in some use cases, they are not the same because they are made for different purposes. Entities implement application agnostic business rules, so if you pass them through the application layer the controllers can access them. You open the door for business logic to diffuse to other layers. Thus you shoud separate these concerns and resist the temptation to use entities as DTOs, just because they look similar in some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "application" or "infrastructure" layer in the clean architecture.
Unfortunately, ChatGPT cannot read books for you, it can only copy past answers from the internet (most of the time wrong ones).
Here are some quotes from the book "Clean Architecture: A Craftsman's Guide to Software Structure and Design". You can think of this book as of single source of truth:

> The architect can employ the Single Responsibility Principle and the Common Closure Principle to separate those things that change for different reasons, and to collect those things that change for the same reasons—given the context of the intent of the system.

> What changes for different reasons?
> User interfaces change for reasons that have nothing to do with business rules. Business rules themselves may be closely tied to the application, or they may be more general. The database, the query language, and even the schema are technical details that have nothing to do with the business rules or the UI.
>
> Thus we find the system divided into decoupled at least four horizontal layers — the application-independent business rules, Application-specific business rules, UI, and the Database.

Next, Uncle Bob explains how to build four layers that follow the Clean Architecture. The names he gives to these layers are not mandatory, but they are commonly used and well-understood by many developers. The layers are:

1. Enterprise Business Rules (Entities)
2. Application Business Rules (Use Cases)
3. Interface Adapters
4. Frameworks & Drivers

The names and layers are arbitrary, as long as they are clear and follow the principles. For example, Uncle Bob sometimes calls the interface adapters layer "UI" and some developers call the frameworks and drivers layer "IO". The key is to separate things that change for different reasons by enforcing encapsulation and following the dependency rule.

Now regarding your question. Again let's reference the author of the clean architecture, what does he say regarding your question:

> Typically the data that crosses the boundaries consists of simple data structures. You can use basic structs or simple data transfer objects if you like. Or the data can simply be arguments in function calls. Or you can pack it into a hash-map, or construct it into an object.

> The software in the interface adapters layer is a set of adapters that convert data from the format most convenient for the use cases and entities to the format most convenient for some external agencies such as the database or the web.

> **Crossing boundaries**.
>
> At the lower right of the diagram is an example of how we cross the circle boundaries. It shows the Controllers and Presenters communicating with the Use Cases in the next layer. Note the flow of control. It begins in the controller, moves through the use case, and then winds up executing in the presenter. Note also the source code dependencies. Each one of them points inward toward the use cases.
>
> [image]We usually resolve this apparent contradiction by using the Dependency Inversion Principle. In a language like Java, for example, we would arrange interfaces and inheritance relationships such that the source code dependencies oppose the flow of control at just the right points across the boundary.
>
> For example, consider that the use case needs to call the presenter. However, this call must not be direct because that would violate The Dependency Rule: No name in an outer circle can be mentioned by an inner circle. So we have the use case call an interface (Shown here as Use Case Output Port) in the inner circle, and have the presenter in the outer circle implement it.
>
> The same technique is used to cross all the boundaries in the architecture. We take advantage of dynamic polymorphism to create source code dependencies that oppose the flow of control so that we can conform to The Dependency Rule no matter what direction the flow of control is going in.

Comment: Thanks for a very detail answer, but I don't really agree with you when you said: "he gave them specific names, you cannot make up other names", Clean Arch is not about what name or how many layer it have, it's about SOLID, Dependency rule ..., Uncle bob have said it in some of conferences that you can find on youtube. anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: @pham Sorry for the confusion, I agree with you that Clean Architecture is about SOLID, Dependency rule, etc. The names and layers are arbitrary, as long as they are clear and follow the principles. For example, Uncle Bob once called the "interface adapters" layer “UI” and some developer called the "frameworks & drivers" layer as “IO”. I do not see anything wrong with that. The key is to separate things that change for different reasons by enforcing encapsulation. Please accept my apology. I edited the text.